# Log in to Ubuntu Wayland in 19.10

Tags: wayland

In the Ubuntu 19.10 Wiki page is said that in order to avoid the fractional scaling problems caused by XOrg one should try to "Log in to Ubuntu Wayland". How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the login page, there is a little gear next to the "login" button.  Click that and one of the choices should have "Wayland" in it.  If it does not, then you probably are using the Nvidia drivers, which are not compatible.  Ubuntu 18.04 would automatically switch to the Intel i915 drivers even when the Nvidia drivers were installed and in use, but looks 19.10 removed that feature.
  Use the nouveau driver instead of the proprietary Nvidia drivers.  From the "Software and Updates" launcher icon, select the additional drivers tab and click on the nouveau button, then click the "Apply" button.  A progress bar will indicate the drivers being reset, wait until it finishes.  Reboot immediately.  Do not just logout, you will get a login-loop trying to get back in, and the restart/shutdown wont work either.  You'd have to start a virtual terminal (ctrl-Alt-F3), login, and sudo shutdown -h -t0 now to shut down the system. Then login should work, and the login screen gear will offer the ubuntu Wayland choice.

Comment: This might explain, why the Wayland option in the login is gone, after upgrading from Ubuntu 19.04 to 19.10. Is there a way to get Ubuntu 19.10 to use Wayland on the Intel integrated graphics in 19.10? I am using the Nvidia GPU only for computation. My system is the Dell XPS 9570 with the 1050Ti.

Comment: You should ask your own question about selecting/switching drivers for Wayland.  I have no idea how to, and don't use 19.10 regularly.